# How to correctly do recursive type definition in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, recursion, types

I have an arbitrary structure consisting of nested arrays and objects, with ValidationError objects as leaves. To type this I need a recursive type as shown in [Typescript guidelines](https://github.com/unional/typescript-guidelines/blob/master/pages/advance-types/recursive-types.md).

While the assignment (`const x = ...`) seems to pass the type check, accessing the structure (`x.errors.a`) gives a TypeScript error which I cannot understand:

> Error: TS2339: Property 'a' does not exist on type 'ValidationResultElement'.
>
> Property 'a' does not exist on type 'ValidationResultObject'.

[see code on TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20ValidationResult%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20errors%3A%20ValidationResultElement%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ValidationResultElement%20%3D%20ValidationResultObject%20%7C%20ValidationResultArray%20%7C%20ValidationError%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ValidationResultArray%20extends%20Array%3CValidationResultElement%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ValidationResultObject%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ValidationResultElement%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ValidationError%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20string%3B%20%2F%2F%20tslint%3Adisable-line%3A%20no-reserved-keywords%0D%0A%20%20details%3F%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%3A%20ValidationResult%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20errors%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%20%7B%20b%3A%20%5B%7B%20c%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20%27A%27%20%7D%20%7D%5D%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ax.errors.a%3B)

```
export interface ValidationResult {
  errors: ValidationResultElement;
}

type ValidationResultElement =
  ValidationResultObject | ValidationResultArray | ValidationError;

interface ValidationResultArray extends Array<ValidationResultElement> {
}

interface ValidationResultObject {
  [key: string]: ValidationResultElement;
}

interface ValidationError {
  details: string;
}

// This works:
const x: ValidationResult = {
    errors: { a: { b: [{ c: { details: 'foo' } }] } }
};

// This produces a type error:
console.log(x.errors.a);
```

Comment: The problem is you may have to tell TypeScript which of the three ResultElements in the union to consider `(x.errors as ValidationResultObject).a`

Answer (score 1):

You need to narrow the type. This is an example but I have caveats!

```
function isValidationResultObject(obj: any): obj is ValidationResultObject {
  return (obj && (!obj.type) && (!obj.length));
}

if (isValidationResultObject(x.errors)) {
  console.log(x.errors.a);
}
```

I have chucked together a custom type guard to eliminate the other types, but it is probably wrong, it just demonstrates the concept. You need to write a type guard that works.

You may find a discriminated union type makes this easier that delving into lots of properties.

You could force the type to narrow with an assertion, but a type guard is more honest and ensures you are really dealing with the type you expect.